# Recommendations for the best MOOC or book about statistical physics

Tags: references

On Amazon, there are over 12,000 references in its "Book" catalogue using the keywords "statistical physics." Similarly, a Google search of the keywords "online MOOC statistical physics" turned up over 100,000 hits.

I would like to cut through all of this and hear what CV participants think are the best resources for learning about "statistical physics."

What are they?

Comment: If "statistical physics" means what it sounds like, your question likely belongs elsewhere because it's about *physics.*  But of course the presence of "statistical" suggests it could be on topic here--depending on what this field means to you.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @whuber, can you move this to http://physics.stackexchange.com/? Physics uses high powered statistics, e.g., for quantum mechanics, but the average statistician would not have studied quantum mechanics, so ask this on the physics site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because statisticians would not know about statistical physics. Please migrate to http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Carl Have you searched that site?  It seems [already to include questions like this one.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22statistical%20physics%22%20wiki%3ayes)

Comment: @whuber Yup, it does indeed. DJohnson, follow whuber's link.

Comment: It seems to me that asking here implies that the interest is in recommendations from statistical people of any kind who know something (preferably a lot) about statistical physics. It doesn't matter if the people who might answer are a very small minority of CV members and we can't be certain that no such people exist here. Hence this question seems to me entirely in order. A question is not off-topic because it's speculated that no one can or will answer it.  (None of that rules out looking elsewhere too, naturally.)

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The (majority) grounds for closing here as "primarily opinion-based" don't convince. We have many threads here asking for book recommendations. Recommendations depend on judgments about what is good. The element of opinion there in that is inevitable and not inherently problematic.

Comment: This is off-topic. Statistical physics has little to do with statistics, science of the state, which is the majority that you encounter here. I personally do know a bit of 'statistical physics' but only from my times before I knew about 'statistics'. Any knowledge that you might find here is by an occasional cross contamination of interests. Anyway, when I was struggling as a student on the concepts of mathematical statistics I used *'Statistical mechanics and thermodynamics'* by C Garrod and *'Thermodynamics and an introduction to thermostatistics'* by HB Callen which are both fine.

Comment: If you use the keywords *"statistical physics" **+** introduction* then you'd get the number of book suggestions on amazon down to <300.

Comment: This question is actually also a duplicate from another SE q&a-site https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/recommendations-for-statistical-mechanics-book (probably there are more) a thread which shows that the question is also off-topic because of the subjective nature and there are no good definite answers (that other site does resources recommends). *(a question which gets a, more, definitive answer would be 'how do I search for a good book about statistical physics' and one tip would already be to be more specific about the exact type of physics in order to cut down the options)*

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to address this query long ago.